# How to cancel a flatMap publisher from a user event

Tags: swift, combine

I have a setup where a user can tap a button to start a series of multiple network requests via a flatMap.  I'd like to allow the user to cancel the network requests by tapping another button.  Calling cancel on the cancellables saved doesn't cancel the requests.  I have this class:

```
class ImageService : ObservableObject, UrlBuildable {
    @Published var currentImage: DownloadImageEvent?
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    private var isCancelled: Bool = false
    
    func downloadImage(at: URL) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage, URLError> {
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: at)
                .compactMap { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
                .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        currentImage = nil
        cancellables.removeAll()
        self.isCancelled = true
        print("\(#function) isCancelled: \(isCancelled)")
    }
    
    typealias DownloadImageEventResult = Result<DownloadImageEvent, URLError>
    typealias DownloadImageEventResultPublisher = AnyPublisher<DownloadImageEventResult, Never>
    
    func downloadAllImages() ->  DownloadImageEventResultPublisher {
        let urls = buildImagesUrls().compactMap{ URL(string: $0) }
        let pub: AnyPublisher<URL, Never> = urls.publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        var index: Int = 0
        let delay: Int = 2
        
        return pub.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { [isCancelled] url -> DownloadImageEventResultPublisher in
            print("\(#function) \(url)")
            index += 1
            
            // download & create event
            print("\(#function) isCancelled: \(isCancelled)")
            
            if (isCancelled) {
                let res = Result<DownloadImageEvent, URLError>.failure(URLError(URLError.Code(rawValue: 404)))
                
                return Just(res).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            } else {
                return self.downloadImage(at: url)
                    .print()
                    .map{ _ in DownloadImageEvent(
                            index: index,
                            total: urls.count,
                            url: url.absoluteString) }
                    .delay(for: RunLoop.SchedulerTimeType.Stride(TimeInterval(delay)),
                           scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                    .convertToResult()
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

I can see that when `cancel()` is called, `isCancelled` is updated but the `flatMap` sees the old value of `isCancelled` because it captured it initially.  So this approach isn't going to work.  I thought of using a private subject and have the `cancel()` send an event to the private subject but how do I get the `flatMap` to cancel in response to events sourced by the private subject?

Comment: Why do you capture `isCancelled`  as _value_? If you omit the capture list and simply use `self.isCancelled` you get the actual value. However, ensure also that `isCancelled` will always be accessed on the same thread to avoid data races. As for your other question: in Combine you can cancel only a "Cancellable", which you receive when subscribing to a publisher. While it's possible, to cancel inner pipes via special input tokens while keeping the outer non-failing pipes intact, and even collect partial results, I would stick with your approach. The latter is way more complicated.

Comment: The other simple approach is to use a sink, which receives each image, stores that internally, and its cancellable will be used to cancel the whole publisher.

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing anything in `cancellables` so calling `cancellables.removeAll()` won't have any effect as the set is empty. In order to cancel the operation you have to do it where `downloadAllImages()` is called from. The call site holds the token and only there can you cancel the subscription.